# i need help understanding liquid coding in shopify

Tags: shopify

this is probably an easy one, I need help with an if statement so my button only shows on specific product types.

```html
 <button id="myBtn">Size Guide</button>
 
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img style="margin:auto; width:100%" class="modal-size-chart" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0278/2842/0746/t/3/assets/{{ product.vendor }}.jpg"></img>
        </div>

    </div>
```

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img style="margin:auto; width:100%" class="modal-size-chart" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0278/2842/0746/t/3/assets/{{ product.vendor }}.jpg"></img>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if product.type == "myType" %}
  <button id="myBtn">Size Guide</button>
{% endif %}
```

More information on `product.type` [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/product#product-type)

More information on if [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags)

Comment: Hey Charles, Thank you! and thank for the links